# Redirect not working for matching a pattern in my url

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect a pattern of urls

```
http://style.com/style-blog/entry/what-im-looking-for-in-my-next-15-inch-laptop
```

to

```
http://style.com/blog/entry/what-im-looking-for-in-my-next-15-inch-laptop
```

I have tried to match the "style-blog" here

```
^style-blog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ or ^style-blog/$
```

I needed to the first version to get ANY remaining part of the url to append to the new url here

```
  RewriteRule    ^style-blog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$    http://style.com/you-blog/$1    [NC,L]
```

Thanks for pointers on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Which strings are fixed and which dynamic? Give examples of one typical incoming URL and one substitution URL, because the last one in your question don't have anything to do with the rewrite rule. So, what is it, the rule or the URL in the example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just be missing a `/`:

```
RewriteRule  ^/style-(blog/[A-Za-z0-9-]+)$  http://style-review.com/$2
```

Using wildcard:

```
RewriteRule  ^/style-(blog/.*)$  http://style-review.com/$2
```

Do you even need the full URL?

```
RewriteRule  ^/style-(blog/.*)$  /$2
```

Are the `^` and `$` required? Wouldn't just this work?

```
RewriteRule   style-blog/   blog/
```

Comment: wow - I had no idea they could be so simplistic ! I am doing some experimentation now - not sure it is the solution exactly yet - thanks

Comment: hmmm nothing seems to be getting matched - for example I cant even redirect to a home page matching as follows
RewriteRule    ^style-blog$     http://style.com    [NC,L]

Comment: @landed I think it should be `RewriteRule ^/style-blog$ ...` or possibly `... ^/style-blog/$ ...`.

Comment: No nothing is getting recognised - htaccess is working for a redirect which removes www from my urls - so it snot that. I just also tried
RewriteRule laptop  http://style.com/ and that didnt work either nor ^laptop$ ..

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^style-blog/(.*)/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/you-blog/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This appears to be working but thanks to you guys you got me on the right track and probably you didn't have enough information to solve it. Its not fully tested yet and might not cope with any extra 'folders' (bits between slashes)